# Horoscope Project (In Need of Help!)

Tags: int, project

I see that the problem is with the int MATHDATE not changing like it is supposed to. Every time I enter a birthday, the sign comes up as Capricorn, because MATHDATE will not change from 0. Can someone please help me fix this? Thank you.

```html
System.out.println("Please enter your birthday in mm/dd format: ");

   Scanner birthdayin = new Scanner(System.in);
   String bmonth = scan.nextLine();
   int bday = Integer.parseInt((bmonth.substring(0,bmonth.indexOf('/'))));
   String horoscope = null;
   int MATHDATE = 0;

   if (bmonth.equals("01") || bmonth.equals("1")){
   MATHDATE = 0 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("02") || bmonth.equals("2")){
   MATHDATE = 31 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("03") || bmonth.equals("3")){
   MATHDATE = 59 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("04") || bmonth.equals("4")){
   MATHDATE = 90 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("05") || bmonth.equals("5")){
   MATHDATE = 120 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("06") || bmonth.equals("6")){
   MATHDATE = 151 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("07") || bmonth.equals("7")){
   MATHDATE = (181 + bday);}
   if (bmonth.equals("08") || bmonth.equals("8")){
   MATHDATE = 212 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("09") || bmonth.equals("9")){
   MATHDATE = 243 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("10")){
   MATHDATE = 273 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("11")){
   MATHDATE = 304 + bday;}
   if (bmonth.equals("12")){
   MATHDATE = 334 + bday;}

   if (MATHDATE >= 20 && MATHDATE <= 49)
   {horoscope = ("AQUARIUS");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 50 && MATHDATE <= 79)
   {horoscope = ("PISCES");}
   else if (MATHDATE >=80 && MATHDATE <=110)
   {horoscope = ("ARIES");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 111 && MATHDATE <= 141)
   {horoscope = ("TAURUS");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 142 && MATHDATE <= 172)
   {horoscope = ("GEMINI");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 173 && MATHDATE <= 203)
   {horoscope = ("CANCER");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 204 && MATHDATE <= 234)
   {horoscope = ("LEO");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 235 && MATHDATE <= 265)
   {horoscope = ("VIRGO");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 266 && MATHDATE <= 295)
   {horoscope = ("LIBRA");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 296 && MATHDATE <= 325)
   {horoscope = ("SCORPIO");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 326 && MATHDATE <= 355)
   {horoscope = ("SAGITTARIUS");}
   else if (MATHDATE >= 356 || MATHDATE<= 19)
   {horoscope = ("CAPRICORN");}


   System.out.println("Your sign is: " + horoscope);
```

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging, like printing out the value of `bmonth` and confirming that it contains what you think it contains?

Comment: You are deriving `bday` from `bmonth`, assuming that `bmonth` contains a `/` character. At the same time, you have 12 equality checks against `bmonth` that assume that `bmonth` contains a formatted number between 1 and 12… but no `/` character. Therefore, your code obviously makes conflicting assumptions about what `bmonth` may contain.

Comment: It looks like you need to set `bmonth` much like you have `bday` (take only part of the input).  Just a quick pointer - even if the first `if` condition is true, all the others will still be evaluated.  Does this language support a select case / switch?

Answer (score 0):

If someone actually does enter their birthdate in that format (say, "12/15"), `bmonth` will be "12/15" (which won't match any of your conditions) because you don't do anything with it to trim the day off after calling `scan.nextLine()`.  Also, I don't know what `scan` is because you named your scanner `birthdayin` which you then don't use.

The quickest change (assuming you resolve the `scan` vs `birthdayin` thing) would be to check for things like `if ((bmonth.startsWith("01/") || bmonth.startsWith("1/"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split the date and do something like this:

```
           Scanner birthdayin = new Scanner(System.in);
           String bmonth = birthdayin.nextLine();
           String[] parts = bmonth.split("/");
           String horoscope = null;

           int M = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            int D = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            if      ((M == 12 && D >= 22 && D <= 31) || (M ==  1 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                horoscope ="Capricorn";
            else if ((M ==  1 && D >= 20 && D <= 31) || (M ==  2 && D >= 1 && D <= 17))
                horoscope ="Aquarius";
            else if ((M ==  2 && D >= 18 && D <= 29) || (M ==  3 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                horoscope ="Pisces";
            else if ((M ==  3 && D >= 20 && D <= 31) || (M ==  4 && D >= 1 && D <= 19))
                horoscope ="Aries";
            else if ((M ==  4 && D >= 20 && D <= 30) || (M ==  5 && D >= 1 && D <= 20))
                horoscope ="Taurus";
            else if ((M ==  5 && D >= 21 && D <= 31) || (M ==  6 && D >= 1 && D <= 20))
                horoscope ="Gemini";
            else if ((M ==  6 && D >= 21 && D <= 30) || (M ==  7 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                horoscope ="Cancer";
            else if ((M ==  7 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M ==  8 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                horoscope ="Leo";
            else if ((M ==  8 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M ==  9 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                horoscope ="Virgo";
            else if ((M ==  9 && D >= 23 && D <= 30) || (M == 10 && D >= 1 && D <= 22))
                horoscope ="Libra";
            else if ((M == 10 && D >= 23 && D <= 31) || (M == 11 && D >= 1 && D <= 21))
                horoscope ="Scorpio";
            else if ((M == 11 && D >= 22 && D <= 30) || (M == 12 && D >= 1 && D <= 21))
                horoscope ="Sagittarius";
            else
                horoscope ="Illegal date";

            System.out.println("Your sign is: " + horoscope);
```